# How can I reverse engineer my JavaScript files with js/uml?

Tags: javascript, uml, reverse-engineering

### Goal

My goal is to get an UML model out of my JavaScript project (consisting of several .js files) and store it as XMI.

### How far I've come

I searched the internet and found out js/uml is the first place to go.

I've managed it to get the js/uml plugin running with Eclipse 3.7.1 (Win32) and a local installation of my pre-downloaded additional plugins:

1. mdt-uml2tools-Update-incubation-I201103290512.zip (installs required org.eclipse.uml2.diagram.clazz 0.10.0)
2. jsuml-eclipse-0.8.4.zip (only works with Eclipse 3.7.1 (Indigo))

I loaded the provided example project jsuml-example-yui-0.8.4.zip into Eclipse and added all my .js files to this project also.

### Problem

Now I'm stuck and do not get it how to call the reverse engineering of my .js files. I can call 'New'->'Other'->'UML 2.1 Diagrams'->'Class Diagram' from the project's context menu, but I don't get the following steps of that assistant dialog, nor do I get it if this is the right way at all. Please, could you help me with an easy understandable click tutorial? The [js/uml homepage](http://gaertner-network.de/jsuml/quick-start.html) does not explain it well enough IMHO. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Is there anybody out there getting it work with own .js files?

Comment: Can you plz update what happened? Were you successful?

Comment: I think (but I'm not sure) that js/uml can only parse .js files which contain specially formatted comments in front of every single function in the source code. My sources don't have it, and so I had the choice of writing hundreds of such comments to get the parser working, or to manually create the UML model. I decided for the latter, though I'm not satisfied that I have to go that way. And it's not clear to me how such formatting of source comments must look like.

Answer (score 7):

Someone adapted UML for web artifact, its called the "WAE" extension of UML. This way you can see not only your javascript files but the html and css. If you work with node.js, i created a module that generate class diagram for javascript/node/html/css. Its called wavi. For javascript, function,variable are automatically recognized. You can use it for documenting your application.

https://www.npmjs.org/package/wavi

[image: Diagram generated by wavi]

Answer (score 4):

Well, I think I have come quite close.

There's a command-line tool called [Code2Flow](https://github.com/scottrogowski/code2flow). which uses [GaphViz](http://www.graphviz.org) to generate graphs for Python and JavaScript sources.

I tried it, it does generate the graphs but somehow i can't make to do right.

I hope this will help you or someone.