# Is there an automated way to generate a sequence diagram from an applications Javascript code?

Tags: javascript, sequence-diagram

I'm trying to find out if there's a way to generate a sequence diagram from our Javascript code.

Either something like that does not exist (yet), or I can't seem to find the good Google query. I always end up with [js-sequence-diagram](https://github.com/bramp/js-sequence-diagrams), which is a tool to generate sequence diagrams using Javascript, but not *from* Javascript code.

Firebugs profiling tool is able to tell you which Javascript methods were called how many times in 1 profiling session. It can also tell you the file in which the Javascript method resides. This kind of tells me it *should* be possible..

Comment: I think this question is pretty off-topic anyway, if you're using Eclipse, I appreciate [JS/UML](http://jsuml.gaertner-network.de/).

Comment: I don't have Eclipse, but might install it if that's the only existing way. Thx, although it seems it can not generate sequence diagrams?
Not sure why this is off topic?

Comment: Because "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."

Answer (score 1):

I was thinking that profiling with with the Developer Tools (Chrome or whatever) might be the only way but then I saw the answers to this question: [How can I reverse engineer my JavaScript files with js/uml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16714718/how-can-i-reverse-engineer-my-javascript-files-with-js-uml)

"code2flow generates callgraphs"

I'll have to give it a try.

Comment: Please provide some feedback here after you tried something. Thank you.